# Credit Card Number Validation

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello I am having trouble with my javascript validation. I am trying to validate a credit card number which I want it to display between 13 and 18 numbers and single spaces.

My Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["checkout_details"]["creditcard"].value;
    if(x.length != 13 || x.length != 18)//if the length is not 13 or 18
    {
        alert("Please enter a valid credit card number");//display message to user;
        return false;
    }    
}
</script>
```

HTML/PHP Code:

```
echo '<form name="checkout_details" action="confirm.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">';
echo '<font color="red">*</font>&nbsp;<b>Credit Card Number:</b> <input type="text" name="creditcard" id="creditcard"><br /><br />';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Purchase">';
echo '</form>';
```

Anyone help me out tell me what i'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: What is the error your getting? Also check out the luhn algorithm when it comes to validating credit car numbers. I also suggest to not just validate these numbers from your client side but also from the server side.

Comment: @scragar the piece about function return values is true, but the onsubmit event only checks for an exact return value of `false`

Comment: Also remember to add a return true at the end of your function.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Tested and confirmed, didn't realise that, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Use the Luhn algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
if(x.length != 13 || x.length != 18)
```

you should use

```
if(x.length != 13 && x.length != 18)
```

in fact, with your original condition, 18 is different from 13, and that would have returned `true`!

Also, that accepts only exact length of 13 or 18, if you want to reject anything shorter than 13 or longer than 18, then you need

```
if(x.length < 13 || x.length > 18)
```

Comment: You're welcome :) if my answer helped you, feel free to upvote it and/or accept it.

Comment: Will do I have to wait 5 minutes to do so :)

Comment: I'm having trouble doing phone number validation as well i need it so it only works if you type in numbers

Comment: `var x=document.forms["checkout_details"]["phone"].value;
    if (!isNaN(phoneInput).value)//if the length is not 13 or 18
    {
        alert("Please enter a valid Phone Number");//display message to user;
        return false;
    }`

Comment: Please ask separate questions, do not ask questions in comments.

Answer (score 2):

You meant

```
if (x.length < 13 || x.length > 18) {
    ...
}
```

The original complains if the length is not exactly 13 **and** 18 characters; that is: **always**, as a string having length of 13 cannot have length of 18 and vice versa; also you want to match all the lengths in between.

Comment: I'm having trouble doing phone number validation as well i need it so it only works if you type in numbers

Comment: `var x=document.forms["checkout_details"]["phone"].value;     if (!isNaN(phoneInput).value)//if the length is not 13 or 18     {         alert("Please enter a valid Phone Number");//display message to user;         return false;     }`

Comment: @user3674827 Please ask separate questions, do not ask questions in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Credit card validation is not that simple. You should use a regex to check it. There are also a large variety of credit card formats.

You can see the different regex' here [Credit card regex'](http://www.richardsramblings.com/regex/credit-card-numbers/)

Comment: I'm having trouble doing phone number validation as well i need it so it only works if you type in numbers

Comment: `var x=document.forms["checkout_details"]["phone"].value;     if (!isNaN(phoneInput).value)//if the length is not 13 or 18     {         alert("Please enter a valid Phone Number");//display message to user;         return false;     }`

Answer (score 1):

Validating credit cards is more than just the length of card number. To properly validate the card number (including the length), you should perform a check against the Luhn Algorithm. Use this code:

```js
const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {Accept: 'application/json', 'X-Api-Key': '[APIkey]'}
};

fetch('https://api.epaytools.com/Tools/luhn?number=[CardNumber]&metaData=true', options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: This is a JS code sample of an API method to check a given card number against the Luhn Algorithm. The response of this method can also be made to provide general information about the card (such as brand, country issued in, issuing bank and more).
All you have to do is register with the provider - PCI Booking, to use this method. While they are a paid service, they also offer free accounts where you can perform these types of actions.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
if(x.length < 13 || x.length > 18)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(x.length > 13 && x.length < 18) //if the length is between 13 and 18
```

There's also a very good plugin for CC validation here

[jquery credit card validator](http://jquerycreditcardvalidator.com/)